# Java not deleting text file

Tags: java

When I test the program within the class, it deletes **temp.txt** fine, but when I call it from another class, it fails to delete. Any help much appreciated! (ps- I haven't attached the class from which I'm calling it)

```
public class txtWriteReadDelete{
public static void deleteRecord(String filePath,String usernameDelete) {
    String tempFile="temp.txt";
    File oldFile=new File(filePath);
    System.out.println("oldFile: "+ oldFile);
    File newFile=new File(tempFile);
    String username="";String password="";

    try {
    FileWriter  fileWriter=new FileWriter(tempFile,true);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    PrintWriter printWriter=new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter);
    Scanner x=new Scanner(new File(filePath));
    x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

    while (x.hasNext()){
        username=x.next();
        password=x.next();
        if(!username.equals(usernameDelete)) {
            System.out.println(username);
            printWriter.println(username + "," + password);

        }

    x.close();
    printWriter.flush();
    printWriter.close();
    boolean deleted = oldFile.delete();
    System.out.println("temp deleted: "+deleted);
    File dump=new File(filePath);
    newFile.renameTo(dump); 
}
catch(Exception E) {
    E.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR");

}
```

Comment: Please make this program simpler, this will help us to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a file using `.delete()` operation expect a valid path. If the path is incorrect `.delete()` would not be able to delete the file.

You can check the validity of the file using `oldFile.isFile()` operation.

You need to provide the complete path of the file.

Comment: it is returning true, so dont think its a problem with the filepath